# Which SCM can comfortably handle 90,000 files

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial, cvs

I have a folder which contains a whitelabel-esque system; theres way over 90,000 files in there.

Currently its stored in SVN and we just checkout the sub-folders as required.

Would mercurial or another SCM be able to handle having the lot checked out at once without it dying when you try to commit.

Comment: Since hg and git usually can't checkout a partial repo, it might not be wise to use them here.

Comment: @tonfa: But you could plan ahead, and make the subfolders submodules of the larger repo...

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, but from my experience people usually find it inferior to subversion in that case.
But note that both hg and git can very well handle 90k files, even if you find it more cumbersome than partial checkouts from subversion.

Comment: @tonfa: You're right - though being inferior to subversion for partial checkouts/submodules might be balanced by other features. And yeah, hg and git are fine with large numbers - it's single operations (commits) touching all 90k files that are bad, or individual large binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some analysis for this here: [Can I use Subversion for a multi gigabyte data set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396737/can-i-use-subversion-for-a-multi-gigabyte-data-set/1399598#1399598)

(Read comments after my answer as well).

Comment: Tonfa added some timings for hg in that question.

Comment: What's the dataset you used? 
Tonfa and you seem to have used the same thing for comparisons O_o

Answer (score 1):

Another vote for Perforce as long as the server isn't running any Windows OS.  I suggest at least a 6 core system with 24 Gb of RAM and a decent RAID under Linux.

Comment: Which translates to a hell of a lot of cash for version control. And our OPs team is very much locked down to Microsoft which of course means we are :o)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would more depend on the capability of your system like RAM, processor speed etc rather than on capability of SCM tool.

Comment: Server has 4gig ram (Win Server 2k3), dual xenon; client machines are ok, dual core, 3.5gig ram, XP.

Answer (score 0):

[Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/) is known for handling large commits fairly well.
See also "[Is Perforce worth it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346031/is-perforce-worth-it)"

But infrastructure aspects need to be taken into account anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perforce and PureCM and the quickest version control tools for checkout and checkin. I would be wary of Perforce if you are planning on branching. Perforce will be VERY slow branching this number of files. PureCM will handle this fine.